# Global/ module variables versus local variables in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am pretty new to programming and using fortran 90 to write a cfd solver that takes a while to run. I am using a module and derived types to store global variables which are used in subroutines in a large do-loop in my main program. I have noticed that if I am referencing one of these global variables and don't need to alter its value, it is slower to use the variable defined in the module than to create a local variable within the subroutine. For instance, I have a type called `grd` with a real constant `A` stored in it. Instead of referencing `grd%A` over and over in a subroutine, it seems to be faster if I create a  local `A` within the subroutine and assign it upfront, `A=grd%A`, and use `A` instead. I've run speed tests and for my particular program and defining this local `A` gives me about a 10% increase in speed, which ends up being pretty significant.

Can anyone explain why this would be the case? Are local variables always faster? Thanks!

Comment: Related on Comp Sci SE: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24776/is-there-any-computational-efficiency-to-global-variables. The difference could come down to compiler optimizations that can be done when you store the value of the attribute locally at the start rather than repeatedly access it from the global object.

Comment: If your compiler is intel `ifort`, you may also want to ask this question in the [Intel Fortran forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler). I am sure the compiler developers there would have interesting insight into this observation.

Comment: We need to see the code and the actual measurements.

Comment: And which compiler, and which compiler flags

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I am using gfortran, no compiler flags

Comment: What happens if you use -O3?